# Sorting query by distance requires reading entire data set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

To perform geoqueries in DynamoDB, there are libraries in AWS (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/geo-library-for-amazon-dynamodb-part-1-table-structure/). But to sort the results of a geoquery by distance, the entire dataset must be read, correct? If a geoquery produces a large number of results, there is no way to paginate that (on the backend, not to the user) if you're sorting by distance, is there?

Comment: Can you give a specific example of how you set up the table schema and what your query looks like? (Not code but actual data samples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. To sort all of the datapoint by distance from some arbitrary location, you must read *all* the data from your DynamoDB table.

In DynamoDB, you can only sort results using a pre-computed value that has been stored in the DynamoDB table and is being used as the sort key of the table or one of its indexes. If you need to sort by distance from a fixed location, then you can do this with DynamoDB.

---

**Possible Workaround** (with limitations)

- **TLDR;** it's not such a bad problem if you can get away with only sorting the items that are within X kms from an arbitrary point.

This still involves sorting the data points in memory, but it makes the problem easier by producing incomplete results (by limiting the maximum range of the results.)

To do this, you need the Geohash of your point P (from which you are measuring the distance of all other points). Suppose it is A234311. Then you need to pick what range of results is appropriate. Let's put some numbers on this to make it concrete. (I'm totally making these numbers up because the actual numbers are irrelevant for understanding the concepts.)

```
A - represents a 6400km by 6400km area
2 - represents a 3200km by 3200km area within A
3 - represents a 1600km by 1600km area within A2
4 - represents a  800km by  800km area within A23
3 - represents a  400km by  400km area within A234
1 - represents a  200km by  200km area within A2343
1 - represents a  100km by  100km area within A23431
```

Graphically, it might look like this:

```
View of A                           View of A23
|----------|-----------|            |----------|-----------|
|          | A21 | A22 |            |          |           |
|    A1    |-----|-----|            |   A231   |    A232   |
|          | A23 | A24 |            |          |           |
|----------|-----------|            |----------|-----------|
|          |           |            |          |A2341|A2342|
|    A3    |     A4    |            |   A233   |-----|-----|
|          |           |            |          |A2343|A2344|
|----------|-----------|            |----------|-----------|  ... and so on.
```

In this case, our point P is in A224132. Suppose also, that we want to get the sorted points within 400km. A2343 is 400km by 400km, so we need to load the result from A2343 and all of its [8-connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_neighborhood) neighbors (A2341, A2342, A2344, A2334, A2332, A4112, A4121, A4122). Then once we've loaded only those in memory, then you calculate the distances, sort them, and discard any results that are more than 400km.

(You could keep the results that are more than 400km away as long as the users/clients know that beyond 400km, the data could be incomplete.)

The hashing method that DynamoDB Geo library uses is very similar to a [Z-Order Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve)—you may find it helpful to familiarize yourself with that method as well as [Part 1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/z-order-indexing-for-multifaceted-queries-in-amazon-dynamodb-part-1/) and [Part 2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/z-order-indexing-for-multifaceted-queries-in-amazon-dynamodb-part-2/) of the AWS Database Blog on Z-Order Indexing for Multifaceted Queries in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. When querying location you can query by a fixed query value (partition key value) and by sort key, so you can limit your query data result and also apply a little filtering.

I have been racking my brain while designing a DynamoDB Geo Hash proximity locator service. For this example customer_A wants to find all service providers_X in their area. All customers and providers have a 'g8' key that stores their precise geoHash location (to 8 levels).

The accepted way to accomplish this search is to generate a secondary index from the main table with a less accurate geoHash 'g4' which gives a broader area for the main query key. I am applying key overloading and composite key structures for a single table design. The goal in this design is to return all the data required in a single query, secondary indexes can duplicate data by design (storage is cheap but cpu and bandwidth is not)

```
GSI1PK  GSI1SK     providerId    Projected keys and attributes
--------------------------------------------- 
g4_9q5c provider   pr_providerId1   name   rating
g4_9q5c provider   pr_providerId2   name   rating
g4_9q5h provider   pr_providerId3   name   rating
```

Scenario1: customer_A.g8_9q5cfmtk So you issue a query where GSI1PK=g4_9q5c and a list of two providers is returned, not three I desire.

But using geoHash.neighbor() will return eight surrounding neighbors like 9q5h (see reference below). That's great because there a provider in 9q5h but this means I have to run nine queries, one on the center and eight on the neighbors, or run 1-N until I have the minimum results I require.

But which direction to query second, NW, SW, E?? This would require another level of hinting toward which neighbor has more results, without knowing first, unless you run a pre-query for weighted results. But then you run the risk of only returning favorable neighbors as there could be new providers in previously unfavored neighbors. You could apply some ML and randomized query into neighbors to check current counts.

---

Before the above approach I tried this design.

```
GSI1PK  GSI1SK       providerId    Projected keys and attributes
--------------------------------------------- 
loc     g8_9q5cfmtk  pr_provider1
loc     g8_9q5cfjgq  pr_provider2
loc     g8_9q5fe954  pr_provider3
```

Scenario2: customer_A.g8_9q5cfmtk So you issue a query where GSI1PK=loc and GSI1SK in between g8_9q5ca and g8_9q5fz and a list of three providers is returned, but a ton of data was pulled and discarded.

### To achieve the above query the between X and Y sort criteria is composed of. 9q5c.neighbors().sorted() = 9q59, 9q5c, 9q5d, 9q5e, 9q5f, 9q5g, 9qh1, 9qh4, 9qh5. So we can just use X=9q59 and Y=9qh5 but there are over 50 (I really didn't count after 50) matching quadrants in such a UTF between function.

Regarding the hash/size table above I would recommend to use this https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html
Geohash length  Cell width  Cell height
1   ≤ 5,000km   ×   5,000km
2   ≤ 1,250km   ×   625km
3   ≤ 156km ×   156km
4   ≤ 39.1km    ×   19.5km
5   ≤ 4.89km    ×   4.89km
...